# Parse string and convert special TEXT link [a href="url"]Text[/a] to HTML link

Tags: php, string, parsing, hyperlink

How to parse a string and change a text link to HTML link.

For example:

```
Hello world: [a href="https://example.com"]See example[/a].
```

To:

```
Hello world: <a href="https://example.com">See example</a>.
```

I have also to determinate the target URL and if a domain is specified I have to add the option target="_blank" to the HTML link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exact input you showed us, you may try the following regex replacement:

```php
$input = "Hello world: [a href=\"https://example.com\"]See example[/a].";
$output = preg_replace("/\[(\/a|a href=\".*?\")\]/", "<$1>", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
Hello world: [a href="https://example.com"]See example[/a].
Hello world: <a href="https://example.com">See example</a>.
```

Comment: But I have to check the a character to be sure it's a bracketed link text.

Comment: Check the updated answer, which replaces only anchor tags.